# How to open specific browser using Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using lang :java framework: testNG

my system has 3-4 versions of Mozilla installed, how can i open instance of specific version of Mozilla. Suppose i have 3.5, 3.6,.... version of Mozilla installed and I want to open 3.6 version and perform my testing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just specify the path to the binary of the version..may be, like-

```
FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("path_to_bin"));
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, profile);
```

Answer (score 6):

Just assign a path to proper version of firefox.exe to webdriver.firefox.bin property.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "c:\\path\\to\\firefox.exe");
```

Answer (score 5):

For firefox

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","path of geckodriver.exe");
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Fro Chrome browser

```
     File file = new File("D:\\selnium webdriver\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath() );
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

For Internet explorer

```
           File file = new File("D:\\selnium webdriver\\driver\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
       WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Comment: the answer for Firefox given here doesn't address the question that was asked regarding multiple versions.

Answer (score 1):

> For Ruby - Chrome

```
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome("desiredCapabilities" => "chromeOptions" => {"binary" => "/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome"})
  @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./chromedriver.exe");  //for chrome
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("WebsiteURL");


System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "./geckodriver.exe");  //for firefox
driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("WebsiteURL");
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood, he wants a specific browser, not a specific driver.